# android Pinning/Kiosk mode for more than one app in a device

Tags: java, android, kiosk, kiosk-mode, pinning

Any way to pin other applications from our app. As we know that the home and recent buttons will be invisible. Then how is it possible to got to some other application to pin it.Basically the requirement is to be able to use the device in kiosk/pinned mode for more than one aaplication.

Comment: if you control both application then start another app using intent

Comment: For authorized lock task mode. My first App will be the device owner.Which will be pinned.Suppose i launch the second App from my first Application then i should disable the pinning of the first app to be able to go to the second app.And since second app will not be my device owner.The pinning will be unauthorized and it will prompt me for pinning the second application which the user can decline.

Comment: use shared uid  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setLockTaskPackages(android.content.ComponentName, java.lang.String[])